# При подключении базы данных MySQL выдаёт ошибку часовых поясов

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, eclipse

Ошибка:

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Çàïàäíàÿ Åâðîïà (çèìà)' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй изменить url строки подключения:
там короче после localhost:3306///

```
"useLegacyDatetimeCode=false" +
"amp" +
"serverTimezone=UTC"
```

только не помню в каких кавычках)